# AWS Lambda throws error Cannot parse config file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, nestjs

I The Node API that is running on AWS Lambda. To create a bundled version of the API and its associated `node_modules`, I used the "nest build --webpack" command, resulting in a single file called "lambda.js". I then created a compressed lambda package(zip file). The zip file also includes a `config` folder. The following is a list of the contents extracted from the zip package.

[image]

I uploaded the zip file to lambda function. Configured the handler name as `dist/lambda.handler`. Upon invoking, lambda is throwing the following exception

[image]

Handler name correct since from the log I see first few lines of handler are executed. The `default.js` file does exists under config folder.
Not sure why lambda is throwing error? What I am missing here?

**UPDATE 1**
log contents of `/var/task` directory

[image: log contents]

Comment: You might want to post your error messages as text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will keep this in mind

Comment: Can you post your webpack configuration? How are you importing the `config` module in your lambda code?

Answer (score 1):

Your dist folder and the config folder are at the same level. Can you please move your config folder inside your dist folder and try testing your change